# How to write a mode method using streams

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write a method to get the mode of a `Collection` using a `Comparator`.

Please can somebody show me what changes I have to make to get this to compile? I do not want to change the signature.

```
static <T> T mode(Collection<? extends T> collection, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t, () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), Collectors.counting()))
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)))
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                     .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

**EDIT**

It turns out I was just using the wrong version. This does not compile using `javac 1.8.0_25`. The exact three error messages are:

```
Error:(40, 47) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
inferred: java.lang.Object
upper bound(s): T,java.lang.Object

Error:(43, 45) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(argument mismatch; invalid method reference
  method getValue in interface java.util.Map.Entry<K,V> cannot be applied to given types
    required: no arguments
    found: java.lang.Object
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Error:(44, 25) java: invalid method reference
non-static method getKey() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

However, I have since upgraded to `javac 1.8.0_65` and it compiles perfectly.

Comment: I think you just have a bad `)`.  Your `collect` should end at `counting` with 3 `)` and one less at the end of the entire statement.

Comment: Strange `TreeMap<? extends T, Long> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(); Set<Map.Entry<? extends T, Long>> entrySet = treeMap.entrySet();` does not even work (eclipse). For me, your lambda breaks down to `<?>` in that step and stops all further access to the entries. or http://ideone.com/jKd2Jb

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. Edited. It still doesn't compile.

Comment: Compiles and works for me on Eclipse. Sorry for this: `collection.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t, () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), Collectors.counting())).entrySet().stream().reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))).map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);`

Comment: If I replace `t -> t` with `Function.identity()`, I no longer get an error saying that the inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s). Granted, I'm using Ideone since I don't have access to my home IDE at the moment, but I still wonder why that works and not what you had.

Comment: Compiles with javac as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right. https://ideone.com/4nkBOg I can't get it to work on IntelliJ though.

Comment: I don't know what the compilation error is, but some explicit type arguments might help wherever they are expected.

Comment: That's what I would have done :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It turned out you need a more recent version of the jdk than I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does not compile with javac prior to Java 8u40. If you still want to make it compatible with older javac versions, you can introduce another generic variable like this:

```
static <T> T mode(Collection<? extends T> collection, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return mode0(collection, comparator);
}

private static <T, TT extends T> T mode0(Collection<TT> collection,
                                         Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t, 
                                  () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), 
                                  Collectors.counting()))
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                                  Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)))
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                     .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

By the way you may use `Stream.max` instead of `reduce` and `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` comparator:

```
private static <T, TT extends T> T mode0(Collection<TT> collection,
                                         Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    return collection.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t, 
                                  () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator), 
                                  Collectors.counting()))
                     .entrySet()
                     .stream()
                     .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                     .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                     .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```